# Javascript stop characters on frames

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, iframe, referer

I created a small PHP to redirect to a page after stripping the referer. It works pretty consistent around browsers, however, it redirects to the wrong url.

```
<script>  
window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML='<form target="_parent" action="http://www.example.com/send.php?year=2015&email=me%40me.com&submit=send+form"></form>';
window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit()
}    
</script>

<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

Rather than taking me to http://www.example.com/send.php?    year=2015&email=me%40me.com&submit=send+form it takes me to http://www.example.com/send.php?

So basically the ? acts like a stop word.
How could it fix it? Any help would be GREATELY appreciated.

Comment: Don't put `?` and parameters in form `action`s. Put them in `<input type='hidden'/>`s.

Comment: So could you tell me please how could i rewrite it so that it still redirects to the full url?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `?` and parameters in form `action`s. Put them in `<input type='hidden'/>`s.

```
window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML="<form target='_parent' action='http://www.example.com/send.php' method='get'><input type='hidden' name='year' value='2015'/><input type='hidden' name='email' value='me@me.com'/><input type='hidden' name='submit' value='send form'/></form>";
```